# Correct way of writing parentheses in Ruby methods?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

What is the "acceptable" or "correct" way to write parentheses in Ruby methods?

Like:

```
puts doc.instance_of?( self.class.superclass.class )
```

or:

```
puts doc.instance_of? ( self.class.superclass.class )
```

or:

```
puts doc.instance_of? (self.class.superclass.class)
```

or:

```
puts doc.instance_of?(self.class.superclass.class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 and 3 are wrong (see @muistooshort's comment).

Between 1 and 4, just pick a style guide and stick with it.  Consistency is the most important thing.  I've been happy with this one which recommends 1 and personally find it cleaner looking:

https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Here's an example of 2 breaking with a method that takes an optional second argument:

```
def f(x, y=1) x + y end

f(1,2) # 3

f(1) # 2

f (1, 2) # syntax error

f (1), 2 # 3!
```

Comment: mmm, I'd say 1 is not idiomatic either, the guide you linked says it also: "No spaces after (". And it looks terrible.

Comment: Actually, `f (x,y)` isn't even valid; if there is a space after the method then the parentheses are being used for grouping. If you're going to use parentheses in a method call they **must** follow the method name without any space between them or the parentheses mean something else entirely. So 1 and 4 are fine, 2 and 3 are generally nonsense.

Answer (score -2):

You can even omit parentheses in Ruby, just like you omitted them for `puts` in all of your examples.  This is the "common way", unless you have complex expressions or precedence issues.

```
puts doc.instance_of? self.class.superclass.class
```

Comment: Omitting parenthesis without good knowledge of precedence and how Ruby parses is asking for problems. Stack Overflow has many questions that are the result of people dropping their use of parenthesis and running into problems with methods and blocks.